# Concavity of a two variable function involving the logarithm function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, logarithms

Let $f(x,y) = y\log(x)$, where $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$. The strict concavity of $f(x,y)$ over $[0,1]^2$ is desired. We know that $f(x,y)$ is strictly concave if the Hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$ is Negative Definite, i.e., $\forall$ $(t,w)\in\mathbb{R}^2-{(0,0)}$, we must have $(t,w)\times K \times (t,w)^T < 0$, where $K$ is the Hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$. In other words, we must have
\begin{equation}
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
    t ~~ w 
  \end{array} } \right]  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1/x \\
    1/x & -y/x^2 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
    t \\
    w \\
  \end{array} } \right] = -\frac{w^2}{x^2}y + 2\frac{tw}{x} = -y\left(\frac{w}{x}-\frac{t}{y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{t}{y}\right)^2 < 0 .  
\end{equation}
This inequality does not necessarily hold for all $(t,w)\in\mathbb{R}^2-{(0,0)}$ and $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$. Does this mean that $f(x,y)$ is not strictly concave over $[0,1]^2$ or are there any other tricks to check the strict concavity?

Comment: Should the $-1/x^2$ be $-y/x^2$?

Comment: @angryavian yes, you're right! fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right. You can also use [Sylvester's criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882174/sylvesters-criteria-and-negative-definite-matrices) to justify this.

Comment: I think it should be Negative Definite in line 3. Positive is for convex functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition (i.e. Jenssen's inequality) instead of negative definiteness. We need to have :

$(\lambda{y_{1}}$+$(1-\lambda)y_{2})$log($\lambda\,x_{1}$$+(1-\lambda)x_{2})$>$\lambda\,y_{1}logx_{1}+(1-\lambda)y_{2}logx_{2}$.

Set $y_{1}=\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $y_{2}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ and $x_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $x_{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$. And $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then

$(\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2}{3})$$\,\,log\dfrac{1}{2}\,\,$>$\dfrac{1}{2}$$\dfrac{1}{3}$$log\dfrac{1}{2}$+$\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2}{3}log\dfrac{1}{2}$

which is false because we have equality and not strict inequality. Thus there is no trick to prove something which is not true!!

Comment: Thanks for your response!